# What theorem are these? (from Scott Aaronson's blog)

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models

Browsing Scott Anderson's blog, I found [this list of theorem](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=152). Among them are:

> If every second or so your computer’s memory were wiped completely
> clean, except for the input data; the clock; a static, unchanging
> program; and a counter that could only be set to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, it
> would still be possible (given enough time) to carry out an
> arbitrarily long computation — just as if the memory weren’t being
> wiped clean each second. This is almost certainly not true if the
> counter could only be set to 1, 2, 3, or 4. The reason 5 is special
> here is pretty much the same reason it’s special in Galois’ proof of
> the unsolvability of the quintic equation.
>
> It would be great to prove
> that RSA is unbreakable by classical computers. But every known
> technique for proving that would, if it worked, simultaneously give an
> algorithm for breaking RSA! For example, if you proved that RSA with
> an n-bit key took n5 steps to break, you would’ve discovered an
> algorithm for breaking it in 2n^1/5 steps. If you proved that RSA took
> 2n^1/3 steps to break, you would’ve discovered an algorithm for
> breaking it in n(log n)^2 steps. As you show the problem to be harder,
> you simultaneously show it to be easier.

I learnt a bit of computer science in college, but I had never heard of these 2. I am very interested in knowing these. Any know what theorems are these? Thanks.

(since I can't comment...can you be more detailed about how "natural proof" do anything here?)

Comment: from answers, these are apparently very deep/ advanced thms in CS that show up in [cstheory.se] typically not addressed at undergrad level. can provide some more detail in [chat]

Answer (score 4):

The first excerpt hints at [Barrington's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)#Barrington.27s_theorem). The second is probably about [natural proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof).

Comment: it would be helpful to be more specific/ detailed how the very abstract thms are converted/ reduced to nearly everyday/ applied statements

Comment: Perhaps you can do that with your own answer.

Comment: its not exactly clear to me how to do that, do not fully see what Aaronson has in mind even with cursory/ rough awareness of the thm constructions, its extremely "sketchy" :|

Answer (score 4):

Scott Aaronson, in a comment on the blog post those came from, gives a reference for each of the theorems. I quote directly from his blog. The first: "Width-5 branching programs can compute NC1 (Barrington 1986); corollary pointed out by Ogihara 1994 that width-5 bottleneck Turing machines can compute PSPACE."

The second: "Natural proofs (Razborov-Rudich 1993); in particular Wigderson’s observation about natural proofs for discrete log."